# OrientDB SQL - traverse while keeping edges weight

Tags: orientdb

Lets assume the following model in OrientDB graph:

I have a *Profile* vertex.
Profiles are connected with 2 edges: *Liked* and *Commented*. Both edges have a "*value*" field indicating the count of the action (or the "weight" of the edge).

So, if user A commented 3 times on posts by user B there will be a *Commented* edge from user A to user B with value = 3.

Now, say I want to get all the users that interacted with user B (either liked or commented), sorted by the weight of the interaction.
I can do that with the following SQL:

```
select * from (traverse out from   
(select out, sum(value) as value from    
(traverse * from (select from Profile where username="B") while $depth < 3)    
where @class="Liked" or @class="Commented" group by out order by value desc)   
while $depth < 2  ) where @class="Profile" )
```

But what if I want to know also the weight of the interaction? How do I propagate up the "value" while doing the last traverse?

**Edit**

According to the suggestion, a simplified version of this query will be:

```
select expand(out) from (    
    select out, sum(value) as value from (    
       select expand(inE("Liked", "Commented")) from Profile 
           where username="B"    
    ) group by out order by value desc 
)
```

But I still can't find a way to use LET to insert the value into the outer expanded object. $parent does not seem to point to the object that is expanded on the most outer select.

**Edit 2**

I'm Playing with $parent in every way I can think of. I don't see how you can use it in this case. Again - the problem I'm trying to solve is how to pass the sum(value) to the outer result set. I don't see a way of using LET for it when doing a GROUP BY, and I also don't see a way of using LET when the outer most select is doing an expand (since you can't do other projections together with expand).

Also, the results of using $current do not seem to be what is expected. For example, the following query:

```
select expand($v) from    
   (select from    
      (select expand(inE("Liked", "Commented")) from Profile where @rid=#11:0)   
    let $v  = $current   
   )
```

Returns this:

```
{  
   "result" : [{  
       "@type" : "d",
        "@rid" : "#14:4",
        "@version" : 2,
        "@class" : "Commented",
        "value" : 1,
        "out" : "#11:165",
        "in" : "#11:0"
    }, {
        "@type" : "d",
        "@rid" : "#14:4",
        "@version" : 2,
        "@class" : "Commented",
        "value" : 1,
        "out" : "#11:165",
        "in" : "#11:0"
    }, {
        "@type" : "d",
        "@rid" : "#14:4",
        "@version" : 2,
        "@class" : "Commented",
        "value" : 1,
        "out" : "#11:165",
        "in" : "#11:0"
    }
]
}
```

The same node over and over again, instead of all the edges, which is what I would expect.

Answer (score 3):

I see you're using an old version of OrientDB. With more recent versions you can simplify it by. Example: original query:

```
select * from (
 traverse out from (
  select out, sum(value) as value from (
   traverse * from (
    select from Profile where username="B"
   ) while $depth < 3
  ) where @class="Liked" or @class="Commented" group by out order by value desc
 ) while $depth < 2 
) where @class="Profile" )
```

You could skip some step by using out()/in()/both() passing the Edge's labels/class like:

```
select expand( out(["Liked","Commented]) ) from Profile where username="B"
```

However to pass the value you can use variables with LET clause. Example:

```
select from XXX let $parent.a = value
```

In this way you set the variable "a" into the upper level context, but you could do also:

```
select from XXX let $parent.$parent.a = value
```

To set it 2 levels up.

Comment: I'm still not sure how to achieve what I'm after. If I'm using the shortened form - select expand( in(["Liked","Commented]) ) from Profile where username="B" - I'm getting the connected profiles, not the edges, so I can't access the value that is on the edge. I also tried to use let in my original query, but it seems that $parent is always empty.

Comment: To be more exact, this part: ' select out, sum(value) as value from (
   traverse * from (
    select from Profile where username="B"
   ) while $depth < 3 '   - aggregates the values of 2 edges and orders the out of the edge by the aggregated sum. I'm not sure how I can express it with the nicer and shortened form. And, I don't see how I can combine a LET with it to pass aggregated value up.
  ) where @class="Liked" or @class="Commented" group by out order by value desc

Comment: If you want the edge use: inE(["Liked","Commented])

Comment: Oh, this is nice. (Is it documented anywhere? I never came across this option). But see my edit - I can't see how I can use LET here. $parent doesn't seem to capture the returned object (which is part of the aggregated query).

Comment: Take a look at: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/SQL-Where#bundled-functions. About $parent the goal is to write a variable in the parent's context

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this with a group by yet, but you should be able to group the result using a sub query. This works for me, where prop1, prop2, prop3, etc are properties of the vertices coming out of the edge (the columns resulting from `select out() Profile where username="B"`)

```
select outV().prop1, outV().prop2, outV().prop3, value from (    
   select expand(inE("Liked", "Commented")) from Profile 
       where username="B"    
) order by value desc
```